# Validacion de inputs Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Tengo un formulario en un Modal, mediante el cual obtengo 2 fechas (fecha inicio, fecha fin)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esos datos alamceno en mi base de datos 1 registro por cada fecha, ejemplo:

- 01-02-2019
- 02-02-2019
- 03-02-2019

Esta es la logica en mi controlador mediante la cual obtengo los datos de esos campos y creo un registro por cada fecha

```
$dateExist = registro::whereBetween('registroFecha', [$request->input('fechaInicio'), $request->input('fechaFin'),])->get();

    if ($dateAbsExist->count() == 0) {
        $fechaInicio = new DateTime($request->input('fechaInicio'));
        $fechaFin = new DateTime($request->input('fechaFin'));
        $fechaFin = $fechaFin->modify('+1 day');
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $period = new DatePeriod($fechaInicio, $interval, $fechaFin);

        foreach ($period as $date) {

            if ($request->hasFile('absenceFile')) {

            $registro = new registro()
            $registro-> = $registroFecha;
            $absence->save();
        }

        $request->session()->flash('msg', 'Ausencia registrada exitosamente');
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('msgClass', 'alert-danger');
        $request->session()->flash('msg', 'El empleado ya tiene una ausencia registrada dentro de las fechas seleccionadas');
    }
```

Esta es la funcion ajax que me envia los datos al controlador

```
<script>
function saveRegistro() {

    $('#saveButton').attr('disabled', true).html("<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;" + "Guardando...");

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('fechaInicio', $('#fechaInicio').val());
    datos.append('fechaFin', $('#fechaFin').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{url('/newRegistro')}}',
        data: datos,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // $('#saveButton').html("<i class=\"far fa-check-square fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;" + "Guardado");
            // location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#saveButton').attr('disabled', false).html("Guardar");
            showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
            markError(['fechaInicio', 'fechaFin']);
        }
    })
    ;
}
```

Este es mi request para validar que la fecha sea requerida

```
return [
     'fechaInicio' => 'required',
     'fechaFin' => 'required|after_or_equal:'.$this->input('fechaInicio'),
                        'note' => 'required|max:300',
      ];
```

Lo que deseo hacer es validar el array de fechas obtenidos para verificar que no existan registros con esas fechas, utilizando el validador que provee laravel. He probado con el metodo unique, pero solo valida la fecha de inicio y la de fin, pero no las fechas que están dentro de ese rango.

O si es posible hacer un return a la función ajax desde el controlador para mostrar el error en el modal. y no como lo tengo que se muestra cuando se refresca la ventana(session flash message).

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres:

1. Tal vez la menos recomendada, sería incluir algo de lógica en el FormRequest y obtener todas las fechas del rango, pasarlas una a una (un while o similar) y generar el array de validación. Lo que no me gusta de esta solución es que agrega demasiada lógica al FormRequest, y la respuesta entregada puede ser un poco confusa.
2. Siguiendo la documentación de Laravel, hacer un validador custom (personalizado), que acepte un parámetro de entrada similar a `after_or_equal` y que haga toda esa lógica de comparación con la base de datos (como `unique`) por aparte y entregue un true o false.

   La documentación para realizar un validador personalizado la encuentras acá: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules
3. Crear un miniservicio (no realmente, pero para entenderlo mejor) de validación en el controlador, y hacer las comparaciones necesarias con la base de datos y entregar una respuesta 422 si no pasa la validación. En otras palabras, teniendo en cuenta que puede haber tanta lógica, pasar la validación al controlador o a un servicio.

**Mi solución recomendada:** la segunda que planteé, mantenemos la lógica de validación fuera del controlador, y no contaminamos el FormRequest, o al menos el array de las reglas y sus «alrededores».